# unordered_map for heap management system. Is a no-collision setup possible?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

The `unordered_map<>` (c++11) uses a hash function to internally organize it's key-values. The collision probability is very small `(1.f/std:numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`).

Is it okay to use an `unordered_map<>` as a storage container for a heap memory management? That is, if two elements get mixed up (by collision) the stability of the program is destroyed. In my case that would lead to repeatedly calling `free()` on the same pointer. (`SIGSEGV`).

Or is the collision probability only important when searching for a key. And it is guaranteed that two different keys always refer to different values?

Follow up question: Say the `unordered_map` with its standard hash function is not okay for my application. If one wanted to make sure that *no* collision can occur, and one can limit oneself to a maximum of `size_t` elements, can one provide her own hash function that returns the argument itself. Something like:

```
template<class T>
struct Hash
{
  size_t operator()(T t) {
    return (size_t)t;
  }
}
```

and be sure of no collisions?

Comment: The expected collision probability is `1.0/m.bucket_count()`.

Comment: You're looking for *(minimal) perfect hashing*. There are some open-source libraries for that.

Comment: @Frank: your hash function will only work if there is a conversion from `T` to `size_t`. Mind you, it is a typical implementation of hashes for integral and pointers. However, collisions occur not only when the hashes are equal, but also when two different hashes are mapped to the same bucket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Collisions only affect performance, not the contents of the container. `unordered_map` takes a hash function *and* an equality function. Two elements can safely have the same hash, and if they compare non-equal then they're treated as non-equal. They'll just always be in the same hash bucket. Large buckets harm performance of operations that look in that bucket.