# Different random points from a 2 dimensional grid

Tags: c++, random

I have a large 2 dimensional grid, let us say 10000 X 10000. From these grid I need to select 1000 random points but I also need to take care that none of the two points are the same. The standard way that comes to my mind is after selecting every point I should check all the previous entries to see if that point has already been selected or not but it seems for large grids and large number of points this will become inefficient. Is there a better way to do it?
I am using C++

Comment: @nim: I would even advise using `std::unordered_set` here, as the values don't need to be ordered. Lookup will be `O(1)` instead of `O(logN)`.

Comment: @LucTouraille, sure, wasn't sure if OP has access to C++11, else boost is a good substitute I guess..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Randomly selecting any point and then discarding it if it exists in the *Selected Points* list should not be inefficient, so long as you have well sorted collection of *Selected Points*, that you can also easily insert into.

Also, depending on how your points are defined (i.e. are they each associated with a class or struct that you've defined), you could add a boolean variable to the point object, named `Selected`.  Once you select a point, check to see if it has been marked as `Selected`.  If not, add it to your list and change the `Selected` value to `TRUE`.  Otherwise, continue on with your selection of random points.

Comment: You probably don't want to create 10000 X 10000 objects (one for each point) especially if only 1000 is selected

Comment: Did you mean to write "efficient" in your first sentence?

Comment: @Attila: You are a correct.  I'm not suggesting that, though.  However, if these points are already part of a large array of structs, representing points, adding a bit to each point shouldn't be a big deal.  It's simply another alternative to answer, but I wouldn't find it to be the optimal one for extremely large lists of data.  Still, it is a viable alternative if the scenario already exists.

Answer (score 3):

> it seems for large grids and large number of points this will become inefficient

Not necessarily. There are two potential sources of inefficiency:

1. Overhead caused by rejection sampling (that is, having to keep trying until you've found a not-yet-selected point). Given that you're choosing 0.001% of the points, the chances of randomly selecting the same point twice are very small. Therefore, the cost of re-trying should be negligible.
2. Overhead of checking whether the randomly chosen point has already been selected. If you store all previously selected points in a suitable data structure, this can be done in `O(1)` time. For this, `std::unordered_set` would be a good candidate. The size of the set will grow linearly in the number of elements you need to select, and will be completely independent of the grid size.

Comment: the hash set will work only if you don't care for omission of some points for occasional hash collision

Comment: @Attila: I beg your pardon? I am basically talking about `std::unordered_set`.

Comment: as with any hash functions, if there are more possibilities than hash values, there will be collision.  I'm pointing out that if there _is_ collision, then some otherwise valid points could be excluded (when their hash collides with a different point already in the hash set)

Comment: @Attila: you can have several keys with the same hash in a hash set. Collisions only affect performance. Steve Jessop explained just that a few hours ago in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10751730/20984).

Comment: @LucTouraille - thx, I was not aware that `unordered_set` used equality as well

Comment: @Attila: It would be pretty useless otherwise (a "lossy" container :))

Comment: I guess my understanding of hash tables was a bit spotty

Answer (score 1):

You could implement an algorithm like this:

> 1. Create an empty mapping from hashes to points
> 2. select random point
> 3. calculate hash
> 4. if hash in mapping, goto 1
> 5. save hash & point
> 6. if not enough points yet, goto 1

Comment: sorry, i did not understand "hashes", can you please elaborate?

Comment: A hash is a one-way 'encryption'; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function for a detailed description

Comment: Better to use an existing hashmap if avaiable

Comment: Yes @Attilla indeed, but that doesn't change the idea behind the algorithm

Comment: Once you've selected one point, the remaining points will no longer be chosen with equal probability (those that hash to the same value as the first point will have *zero* probability of being selected).

Comment: @aix If this is a problem, either use a different hash function or a different algorithm :) But in most practical situations this won't be a concern.