# How to select distinct random points in grid

Tags: python, algorithm, random, time-complexity

I have a 2D list, I need to select `n` distinct random points (x, y coordinates) from this 2D list. Let me first write what occured to me when I tried to solve the problem.

Let's say the grid is `300 x 400`.

- Do cartesian product `300 x 400` get a list of `120000` elements, than use `random.choice` **(Slow for large grids)**
- Keep the selected points in a set, randomize again in a while loop if a duplicate point is produced. **(Very slow and unpredictable if n is large)**

I searched some similar questions in SO, none of them address the problem directly. I did found [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754392/different-random-points-from-a-2-dimensional-grid), though the users answer the problem, they do not offer a Python solution, which we may produce here in this question. Maybe usage of appropriate data structures in Python standard library can be suggested if not code itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) to sample without replacement from a range -- there's a fast special case for range objects. `divmod(i, h)` is the lexicographic mapping from `i` in the 1D range with `w * h` elements to `(x, y)` in the 2D grid.

Python 3:

```
import random
def samplegrid(w, h, n):
    return [divmod(i, h) for i in random.sample(range(w * h), n)]
```

Python 2:

```
import random
def samplegrid(w, h, n):
    return [divmod(i, h) for i in random.sample(xrange(w * h), n)]
```

Comment: This appears to be working, could you please explain how does this work and how it avoids duplicates ?

Comment: @Rockybilly `random.sample` samples without replacement. I linked the docs.

Comment: I used `random.sample` before, just the trick with the dividing confused me, dividing the random number to `h` actually provides distinction ?

Comment: @Rockybilly It's the quotient and the remainder, so yes. The inverse is `lambda x, y: x * h + y`.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I have another question, what if I wanted to select points with a minimum distance between them. If i wanted to accomplish this, where should I begin researching ?

Comment: @Rockybilly Depends on how picky you are about the distribution. If approximately uniform is OK, use a [cover tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_tree) to find the previous point closest to a randomly chosen candidate, retaining those candidates that are sufficiently far.